# Simplifying multiple update statements - KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a table that contains multiple flags, I want to map each of these flags to the values they represent.

```
tab:([] t:til 4 ; f1:1100b;f2:1010b;f3:0101b;f4:0011b )
```

How to simplify these multiple update statements?

```
tab:update f1s:`googl from tab where f1
tab:update f2s:`appl from tab where f2
tab:update f3s:`amzn from tab where f3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can also be achieved by using dictionaries :

```
tab:([] t:til 4 ; f1:1100b;f2:1010b;f3:0101b;f4:0011b )
g:01b!``googl 
ap:01b!``appl 
az:01b!``amzn

update f1s:g@f1, f2s:ap@f2, f3s:az@f3 from tab
```

This is particularly useful in cases when there are multiple values in a single column :

```
q)tab:([] t:til 4 ; f1:1 2 0 4;f2:2 3 4 1;f3:1 4 3 1 ;f4:1 1 0 0 )
q)m:1 2 3!`googl`appl`amzn 
q)update f1s:m@f1, f2s:m@f2, f3s:m@f3 from tab

t f1 f2 f3 f4 f1s   f2s   f3s
-------------------------------
0 1  2  1  1  googl appl  googl
1 2  3  4  1  appl  amzn
2 0  4  3  0              amzn
3 4  1  1  0        googl googl
```

Answer (score 5):

``` update f1s:``googl f1,f2s:``appl f2,f3s:``amzn f3 from `tab ```

you can put the symbols in a list and use the booleans to index into it

Answer (score 1):

A more functional solution

```
q)@/[tab;`f1`f2`f3;(``goog;``appl;``amzn)]
t f1   f2   f3   f4
-------------------
0 goog appl      0
1 goog      amzn 0
2      appl      1
3           amzn 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector conditional operator [`?`](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/10_Execution_Control/#1013-vector-conditional-evaluation) :

```
?[vb;exprtrue;exprfalse]
```

Simplfied statement:

```
update f1s:?[f1;`googl ;`], f2s:?[f2;`appl ;`], f3s:?[f3;`amzn ;`] from tab
```